# Envío parámetro formulario por GET,

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un formulario que si envío por POST me funciona sin problema. Pero quería poder acceder al resultado vía URL. Para ello hago un envío por GET del formulario pero ya no me pasa el dato, y al recibirlo en el PHP evidentemente da error. Creo que lo hago bien, pero también es cierto que es la primera vez que lo intento hacer.

```
function objeto(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById("formulario");
    obje = document.getElementById('elemento');
    var txt='';
    txt ="'"+obje.value+"'";
    url_obje = 'elemento='+txt;
    xhr(url_obje);
}
var xmlhttp;

function xhr(formu){ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            var datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for(var i in datos.data){
                if(datos.data[i].id_code === ""){
                        document.getElementById("text-flag").innerHTML = "";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("text-flag").innerHTML = "<span class='texto'>CÓDIGO: </span><span class='text'>"+datos.data[i].id_code+"&nbsp;</span>";
                }
                if(datos.data[i].name === null){
                    document.getElementById("nameOf").innerHTML = "";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("nameOf").innerHTML = "<span class='textFlag'>Nombre: </span>"+datos.data[i].name;
                }
                if(datos.data[i].description === null){
                    document.getElementById("descripcion").innerHTML = "";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("descripcion").innerHTML = "<span class='boldes'>descripción: </span>" +datos.data[i].description;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "busqueda.php?elemento=txt", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(formu);
}
```

en el inspector de chrome ya veo que el dato no lo envía

```
elemento: txt
```

Cuando con POST si me lo envía, por ejemplo:

```
elemento:'186'
```

Ahora intento recogerlo en busqueda.php

```
if (isset($_GET['elemento'])) {
    //$especie = $_GET["elemento"] ?: ''; 
    $especie = $_GET['elemento'];
    //echo $especie;
}
$consulta = "SELECT id_code, name, description FROM table WHERE id_code = $especie ORDER BY name;

$statement = $cnn->prepare( $consulta );
    
$valor= $statement->execute();

if( $valor ){
    while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data["data"][] = $resultado;
    }
    echo json_encode( $data );
}else{
    echo " error";
}

$statement->closeCursor();
$conexion = null;
```

Pero me da el error

```
txt error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la peticiones `GET`  debes pasar `null` en el método `send`, el cual se usa para mandar el body de la petición (precisamente las peticiones GET no tienen body, los datos viajan en la URL).

Significa que los datos deben viaja aquí:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "busqueda.php?elemento=txt", true);
```

Cosa que tampoco estaría ocurriendo correctamente, pues simplemente estás mandando el valor `txt` como tal, no la variable que construyes más arriba y que estarías guardando en `url_obje`.

Para corregir eso cambia la parte de la petición así:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "busqueda.php?"+url_obje, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send(null);
```

Luego, el control en tu código PHP es precario. Deberías meter la parte de la consulta dentro del `if` y hacer buen uso de las consultas preparadas:

```
$especie=!empty($_GET['elemento']) ? $_GET['elemento'] : NULL;
if ($especie) {
    $consulta = "SELECT id_code, name, description FROM table WHERE id_code = :id_code ORDER BY name;
    $statement = $cnn->prepare($consulta);
    #Cambia PDO::PARAM_INT por PDO::PARAM_STR si id_code no es numérica
    $statement->bindParam(':id_code', $especie, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $data=array();
    if( $valor=$statement->execute() ){
        while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $data["data"][] = $resultado;
        }
        $statement->closeCursor();
    }else{
        $data["error"]="Error en la consulta";
} else {
    $data["error"]="No se recibieron datos con GET";
}
$conexion = null;
echo json_encode($data);
```

Finalmente, la técnica que he usado aquí, para dar **coherencia** al código, ha sido poner una clave `error` en la respuesta de servidor cuando ocurra una situación errónea (dentro del marco de una respuesta 200).  Son errores que corresponden a la lógica de la aplicación, no de problemas de servidor. Adapta tu código en `onreadystatechange` buscando si el JSON tiene una propiedad `error` para actuar en consecuencia. A cada situación de `error` he asociado un mensaje personalizado, por si quieres informar al usuario del motivo del error lógico.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano lo he probado pero si no le pongo la url no me devuelve nada (no lo encuentra), quiero decir, pongo en el `xhttp.open("GET", "busqueda.php?"+url_obje+"", true); `y así por lo menos me devuelve un json con los datos. Pero estoy viendo que como aparte de la búsqueda por select, uso una búsqueda visual por imágenes y categorías, esto me obligaría a cambiar toda la programación.

Comment: @Esti19 sí, hubo un pequeño error en mi respuesta al no incluir la parte de `busqueda.php?` ... Esto resuelve el problema concreto que planteas aquí,  lo otro que comentas no lo he entendido. Tú puedes tener si quieres un sólo código que gestione las peticiones pasándole en parámetro el método, los datos, la URL etc y determinando la forma de leer esa respuesta, si pide o recibe archivos, imágenes, etc.  si quieres reutilizar código o algo así. Pero eso sería yo otro asunto. Además, hoy día existen APIs más modernas como `fetch`.